# Silverlight plugin crash

Tags: silverlight, iis

I have encountered numerous times when a silverlight program is running perfectly, but after a random interval, I will see the silverlight plugin crash message.

It happens on my own projects before which just display a static page with UI for me to test.
Was running on localhost.

Happened at a networked area where my frenz access my iis server to view the page. Was fine the whole morning, but few hours after lunch, it crashed.

I saw it crashed on this site too.
http://www.silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/animations/

Any1 know what's the reason for crash, especially when im hosting it on localhost running a static UI page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very broad topic as there may be numerous reasons the plugin is crashing ... sometimes it might not have anything to do with the plugin itself! It could be other plugins, anti-virus software, viruses, etc.

The best way to diagnose the problem is to take the crash dump and debug it. When the browser crashes, it should generate a file. You can learn how to find those files and inspect them here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315263

Also take a look at this tutorial:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/windbg_part1.aspx

Finally, if you do find the issue, please share it with us ... always good to know what features might cause Silverlight to crash. It has been completely stable on my machine (Win 7 64-bit using both IE 8 and FireFox) with no crashes so I'm curious what might have your machine going through hoops.

Comment: thanks for your answer.
I also got confused with the crashing, some times it crashed.
Some times I can run the whole night while I sleep w/o crashing.
The thing is that be it crash or not, when I test whether it will crash, I'm using the same file.

Worst of all, I even saw it crashed at the silverlight website but didnt know where to extract the plugin crash file.

I will go look through it, and hopefully it provide me with answers that I need

Comment: I didnt have any previous dump before although it was set to kernel memory dump. Just changed it to small memory dump, guess have to wait for it to crash on me again b4 I can try to figure out